# how to connect to database in PHP using my login.cnf

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have used mysql_config_editor to create a login CNF on my server.

In php , is it possible to use this file to store login credentials for the database?
I can use it with a shell script using:

```
--login-path=blah
```

Currently I use the following code to connect:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$serverName.";dbname=".$database, $username, $password);
```

Is there a way to use the CNF file to connect to the database in PHP?

Comment: you can use parse_ini_file() to get credentials from this file